# Fibre Installation

Tags: networking, switch, optical-cable

In my home I have a 3com baseline switch in the attic with Broadband entering the living room then running over cat 6 to the attic.

I am looking to upgrade this to Fibre with the future support of 10GB can someone tell me the cheapest mechanism to achieve this.

2 Trancievers that convert fibre to Ethernet?

Kind of lost when it comes to fibre links.

Or alternatively cat 7

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some converters from RJ-45 to SFP and maybe also SFP+, however it's not the cheapest way. The Cat6 is also capable of 10GBASE-T link speed (up to 55m). So the best if you stay on existing cables. If you require longer distance (up to 100m), Cat6a or Cat7 is your solution.

Otherwise optics in home isn't the best idea, unless you don't know where else to spend your money ;-)